# Java - Collection of abstract class, children contain disparate objects - Any "good" way to handle these wrapped objects?

Tags: java, generics, collections, types, erasure

Let's say we have something like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    //Stuff in here
}

public class MyClassA extends MyClass {

    private String thingie; //Along with getter/setters, of course
    //Other stuff
}

public class MyClassB extends MyClass {

    private List<Integer> thingies; //Again, getters and setters to go with
    //Other stuff
}
```

Let's assume we have any number of classes that extend MyClass, each with it's own instance variable of a different type, although some may have the same type. This is an unfortunate necessity. Now, let's assume we have a Collection of MyClass. We have a collection filled with any number of child classes, each with an object contained within. Let's say I need to iterate over this Collection, retrieve said object from any number of elements, and perform actions upon it, store it, manipulate it, send it elsewhere, etc. These objects have nothing in common aside from extending Object.

I might be able to simply delegate these actions into the MyClass children themselves, use a visitor, etc, but this likely isn't feasible as these actions may be dependent upon other MyClass children in the Collection. A single MyClass child likely won't dictate the action to be taken all by itself, or even any single Collection of MyClass. Some of these actions may be cumulative and dependent upon a number of other potential cumulative factors.

Is there any "good" way to handle this, or am I just going to be cursed to the hell of ugly typechecking conditionals or something similar? I considered using Generics in MyClass and using concrete types on all of the children. This could simplify the retrieval of objects, but would still necessitate a large conditional block.

Comment: Is not a problem of generics or similar. The problem is to find a good pattern to achieve the result

Comment: Your real problem is that you're globbing these together into a `Collection<MyClass>` in the first place with no other information kept.

Comment: That too, Bellabax. :) The problem was simplified, but there is other information. The collection comes from a chained series of tasks submitted to a thread pool. Each task will execute, place a response object in a collection, then, based on the results, determine what the next task should be. This continues until the end is reached, at which point the collection is returned and the main thread evaluates the results. The actions taken depend on many factors, some potentially beyond the data that exists only in that collection, ie, if other jobs in the pool had similar results.

Answer (score 0):

You discarded in your question the "good" way of doing it.  Generics will not help in this case.  Yes, you are going to be cursed to a nasty place for the ugly use of type checking.  You can disguise the type checking using a common instance member called, say, `category` and its corresponding accessor `getCategory` defined in `MyClass`.  And them do a `switch` if you can (instead of multiple `if`s) on `getCategory()`.  However, the people who will condemn you could dislike `if`s and `switches` no matter if they are checking for types or not.  And they could also be smart and understand what you are trying to do.  Anything but

```
for(MyClass e: collection )
    e.doYourAction();
```

is "bad".

Now, for software that seems to have no specification at all, you could be pardoned.

Comment: Conditional typechecking? I don't know if I'd call that "good" so much as "least bad". ;) It's just an ugly chunk of code that's not very dynamic and would have to be changed every time a child of MyClass is added, removed, or perhaps even altered. I realize that this may be the "best" option, but I was hoping for something a bit cleaner and more dynamic. I added the idea of generics in there as a way of tossing ideas around. Sure, that would let me push the object up into the abstract class, but I'd still need to typecheck the danged things.

Comment: @user1017413  What if you explain the problem in a much more general way?  There is something that I could be missing.  In particular, if each new class is going to be that much different to the others, then you will need to change the "ugly chunk of code" anyways every time a child of MyClass is added, removed, or perhaps even altered.  Or is it there anything among them that makes you think you could not?  Are you sure they don't have any commonality at all?

Comment: There's the commonality of each of these MyClass children inheriting from MyClass and contains an object along with some other, more unified information, but the object within could be a variety of types. Each of these is built as a response object for a matching task object, most of which talk to external services. A new/altered class would require its own block to handle the enclosed object (different types mean different handling) and the logic of determining what to do with it based on a multitude of factors.